# LESS compiler for PHP

Tags: php, javascript, v8, less

I'm trying to compile [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) from PHP and don't want to use node.js or ruby.

There's this [PHP implementation](http://leafo.net/lessphp/) I found through Google but it seams really outdated and lacks support for newer features.

I was thinking of using the [V8js](http://php.net/v8js) API to run less.js, would that work since it has no DOM support?

Basically my question is: How can I run this JS file from a PHP application?

Comment: `exec('lesscss foo.less')` :-) Nothing forbids you from executing `less` from PHP :)

Comment: Also, why are you compiling it at runtime? Should you just compile it pre-deployment?

Comment: @arnaud576875: that would be the ruby approach I don't want to use, wouldn't it?

Comment: @JohnD: Because it's a lot of less files and each of my views uses a different combination of them. I have to compile and cache on the fly.

Comment: @Tom, it would, and looks perfectly fine. I think *less* is smart enough to re-compile only the files you modified, so you can easily compile them in real time during dev. (At least I do that with SASS/SCSS, and I have the same many-files approach.)

Comment: @arnaud576875 http://askubuntu.com/questions/22180/less-app-like-application/24045#24045

Comment: @Tom How about you compile each at deployment and then your script can simply put them together as if they're seperate CSS files.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the answer:

https://github.com/leafo/lessphp

There's no other way for the moment.

Comment: A run through on getting LESSPHP working completely autonomously (compile, cache and serve - and you just need to reference your LESS file in your HTML as you would CSS): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274628/compile-less-css-with-php

Comment: this doesn't perform too well on large amounts of less

Comment: There's another less compiler available now: https://github.com/oyejorge/less.php

Answer (score 1):

If you want completely hands-free LESS compiling, try Relayer:

http://relayer.co

It's free and very simple to use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [PhpLessDemandBridge](https://github.com/sotastudio/PhpLessDemandBridge) for that

You can simply use it in your Templates, like:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="css/engine/css.php?file=bootstrap.less" />
```

The Engine can be configured via config file, where you define your path to the less files and cache files.

By defining "css.php?file=bootstrap.less", you point the Engine to the bootstrap file, which imports other less files e.g. Twitter Bootstrap or such.

I am using this for Magento, TYPO3 CMS and many more.

In the first line, i am including needed parts of Twitter Bootstrap - after that i am including my own theme and overrides.

Comment: this is just a wrapper for the previously mentioned lessc.

Answer (score 0):

Good news! We have new Less compiler for this case:
https://github.com/wikimedia/less.php

It has no namespace issues and is easy enough to add and use.