# How to use/compile LESS for Bootstrap?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, less

I would like to take advantage of Twitter Bootstrap but would also like to compile LESS with php not js Can anyone post an example how to do this with php since I am not able to find any references of this online. I am new to LESS and Bootstrap , so please if you can add few details. Thank you!

Comment: LESS PHP? http://leafo.net/lessphp/

Comment: I am on it , reading docs but the actual compile process is not clear , for bootstrap , how to include it ,  include php class and than ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using [lessphp](http://leafo.net/lessphp/).

A simple setup to compile the principle Bootstrap LESS files would be:

```
<?php
  require "lessc.inc.php";

  $less = new lessc;
  $less->checkedCompile("bootstrap.less", "bootstrap.css");
  $less->checkedCompile("bootstrap-responsive.less", "bootstrap-responsive.css");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also compile LESS on your machine locally. There are a bunch of GUI Apps out there to help you with that.

See also this question: [Compile a referenced LESS file into CSS with PHP automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274628/how-to-compile-less-server-side-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

http://lessphp.gpeasy.com/Bootstrap less php compiler for bootstrap 3.1.1