# CSS: Specific fonts for different sizes

Tags: css, fonts

I want texts smaller than 14px to be `Tahoma` and larger to be `Sans Serif` only using CSS3 `font-face` property and without any extra class.

Is it possible using `font-face` and how ?

Comment: I don't think you can define a font-size-range in the font-face specs:
http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#font-face-rule.

If you're already making some of the text smaller (via css I suppose), why wouldn't you add font-family:Tahoma to these rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible with `font-face`, but possible with [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) using mixins and guards. As you can see, you need to define your font sizes slightly different - but that's it. Font-family declarations are based off this value.

I would highly recommend transitioning to LESS (or SASS). LESS runs client side, but there are ways to compile it server side and deliver it as CSS. See [Compile a referenced LESS file into CSS with PHP automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12274628/compile-less-css-with-php)

```
.fontSize (@a) when (@a >= 100) {
    font-family: Impact, Charcoal, sans-serif;
}
.fontSize (@a) when (@a < 100) {
    font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
}
.fontSize (@a) {
    font-size: @a;
}


.cs {
    .fontSize(50px) 
}
.imp {
    .fontSize(110px)      
}
```

---

```
<div class="cs">comic sans font family</div>    

<div class="imp">Impact font family</div>
```

[image: screen shot]

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible by font-face.
but you can have two different classes for different size like

```
.tohama{}
.sanserif{}
```

Comment: Without classes as i mentioned !

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible. There is in general no connection between distinct properties, such as `font-family` and `font-size` in CSS. (Shorthands like `font` set several properties, but otherwise they do not change this.) CSS intentionally lacks programming features: you cannot make the value of a property depend on what has been set to another property as value. There are few exceptions to this; among them, `font-size-adjust` may seem related, but it works the other way around, and indirectly: it adjusts the font size according to the features of the font.

So no CSS solution. In JavaScript, you could investigate the style settings of elements and change font family if the computed font size is larger or smaller than some threshold. But it gets somewhat dirty, and you would probably need to traverse the entire document tree for that.