# SASS and/or LESS - can I create dynamic CSS files on the fly?

Tags: php, cakephp, compiler-construction, sass, less

I'm using CakePHP to build my site (if that matters).  I have a TON of elements/modules each having their own file and fairly complicated CSS (in some cases).

Currently the CSS is in a massive single CSS file, but for sanity sake (and the below mentioned details), I would like to be able to keep the CSS in it's own respective file - ie `css/modules/rotator.css`.  But with normal CSS, that would call a TON of CSS files.

So, I started looking into SASS or LESS per recommendation.  But - it seems these are supposed to be compiled then uploaded.  But in my case, each page is editable via the CMS, so a page might have 10 modules one minute, then after a CMS change it could have 20 or 5...etc.  And I don't want to have to compile the CSS for every module if it's not going to use it.

Is there a way I can have a ton of CSS files that all compile on the fly?

Side note:  I'd also like to allow the user to edit their own CSS for a page and/or module, which would then load after the default CSSs.  Is this possible with SASS and/or LESS?

I don't need a complete walkthrough (though that would be awesome), but so far my searches have returned either things that are over my head related to Ruby on Rails (never used) or generic tutorials on each respective CSS language.

Any other recommendations welcome.  I'm a complete SASS/LESS noob.

**Clarified question:**

How do I dynamically (server-side) combine multiple CSS files using LESS?  (even a link to a resource that would get me on the right track is plenty!)

Comment: Can you describe your goal more specifically? It sounds like you want to use LESS/SASS to output files per-module, which is possible, but will require you to manage which are included from each edited course.  When you say you don't want a huge file do you mean as source CSS or as output?  Yes SASS/LESS can compile 50 little scss/less files into one big css file, or multiple files, but you need to configure it to do so.  My advice: get less or sass running and try stuff- the problem will become more clear and may sort itself out on its own. ;)

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12274628/1455709

Answer (score 6):

If you want to reduce the number of CSS files & you have one huge css file that has all the component css, just link to it on all pages & make sure you set cache headers properly.

They will load the file once and use it everywhere.  The one pitfall is initial pageload time; if that's not an issue go with this solution.  If it is an issue consider breaking down your compiled CSS files to a few main chunks (default.css, authoring.css, components.css eg.).

Don't bother trying to make a custom css for each collection of components, you will actually be shooting yourself in the foot by forcing users to re-download the same CSS reorganized in different ways.

Comment: I understand, but I thought LESS/SASS would allow me to keep my CSS files organized better than just a single huge file.  Even if I combine it on the back-end, that would be a lot nicer to have a file per module, then have them combine into a single file.

Comment: "I don't want to call a bunch of CSS files." -- "I don't want a huge CSS file."  Pick one.

Comment: You're miss-quoting me.  I don't want a single CSS file for development, as that would be an absolute PAIN to maintain.  However, I WOULD like to be able to combine all the module CSS files (as well as other CSS files) into a single (or a few) large CSS file for the front-end-user.

Comment: This answer is informative, but it's not an actual answer to my question.  It explains one of the options I already suggested in my question, but doesn't give even a hint of how to do it.

Comment: "I WOULD like to be able to combine all the module CSS files (as well as other CSS files) into a single (or a few) large CSS file for the front-end-user" Use sass. ///

also: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)  It seems like you already know the answer (use sass) but haven't actually tried using it yet.  Go try it, if how to use it isn't clear, come back with a more specific question than "how can I structure my CSS? Should I use sass or less?"  TIAS :)

Comment: "I don't need a complete walkthrough (though that would be awesome), but so far my searches have returned either things that are over my head related to Ruby on Rails (never used) or generic tutorials on each respective CSS language."  Even a link to a page explaining what I think is possible with LESS would be GREAT, but so far, I've not found anything.  Maybe it's because I don't know the right terminology, but... I've added a revised/shorteneed question to my question.

Answer (score 3):

Check out lessphp (http://leafo.net/lessphp/). It's a php implementation of less and can recompile changed files by comparing the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that 'on the fly' means 'on pageload', that would likely be even slower than sending multiple files. What I would recommend is recompiling the stylesheets whenever a module is saved.

Comment: This is likely what I would want to do, but - HOW?  Even a point in the right direction would be very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The issue of requiring only necessary modules should be solved by means of CMS. It has nothing to do with SASS or LESS.

If your CMS is aware of which modules current page has, do not run a SASS/LESS compilation (it will be painfully slow unless you implement caching which is not a trivial task). Instead, adjust your CMS's logic so that it includes each module's CSS file.

Advanced CMSs like [Drupal](http://drupal.org/) not only automatically fetch only necessary CSS files, but also assemble them into a single file and compress it.

And if your CSS is not aware of which modules current page has (e. g. "modules" are simply HTML code that is saved into post body), then you can't really do anything.

UPD: As **sequoia mcdowell** says in his answer, making users download one large CSS file once is better than making them download a number of lesser CSS files that contain duplicate code. The cumulative size of all those smaller CSS files will turn out to be larger than the size of a full CSS file.

Comment: I was under the assumption I could have many many css files, then use SASS or LESS to combine them, and keep it as a cached file - y/n?

Comment: Yes, this is possible with SASS and LESS. But you will still have to adjust your CMS logic to make it include the necessary CSS file among several available. But sequoia mcdowell is right, this approach is faulty. Let's say you have some common CSS code worth 100KB and five modules 20KB each. This makes a 200KB cumulative CSS file. If you create separate files, you will have a number of them with sizes varying between 120 and 200KB. Users visiting different pages will be forced to download each of them, resulting in ~1MB of CSS instead of 200KB (which is downloaded once and cached in browser).